# Create a new column using the names of existing columns

Tags: r, dataframe, max

From a data frame in this structure

```
   1         2         3
0.2393876 0.3388785 0.4217339
0.2984463 0.3948705 0.3066832
0.3042033 0.3321453 0.3636514
0.2290906 0.2796392 0.4912702
0.1971198 0.3273682 0.4755120
0.2328518 0.3991225 0.3680256
0.3031909 0.3790213 0.3177878
0.2734835 0.3233044 0.4032121
0.3190916 0.3256503 0.3552581
0.2600000 0.3281130 0.4118871
```

How is it possible to compare the value in the three columns, find the highest and add the name of the column in a new variable. Example output:

```
1         2         3              highestcolumn
    0.2393876 0.3388785 0.4217339      3
    0.2984463 0.3948705 0.3066832      2
    0.3042033 0.3321453 0.3636514      3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `which.max` and `apply` on each row.

```r
df$highestcolumn <- apply(df, 1, which.max)

> df
          X1        X2        X3 mean
1  0.2393876 0.3388785 0.4217339    3
2  0.2984463 0.3948705 0.3066832    2
3  0.3042033 0.3321453 0.3636514    3
4  0.2290906 0.2796392 0.4912702    3
5  0.1971198 0.3273682 0.4755120    3
6  0.2328518 0.3991225 0.3680256    2
7  0.3031909 0.3790213 0.3177878    2
8  0.2734835 0.3233044 0.4032121    3
9  0.3190916 0.3256503 0.3552581    3
10 0.2600000 0.3281130 0.4118871    3
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use `max.col`

```
df$highestcolumn <- max.col(df, "first")
```

-output

```
> df
           1         2         3 highestcolumn
1  0.2393876 0.3388785 0.4217339             3
2  0.2984463 0.3948705 0.3066832             2
3  0.3042033 0.3321453 0.3636514             3
4  0.2290906 0.2796392 0.4912702             3
5  0.1971198 0.3273682 0.4755120             3
6  0.2328518 0.3991225 0.3680256             2
7  0.3031909 0.3790213 0.3177878             2
8  0.2734835 0.3233044 0.4032121             3
9  0.3190916 0.3256503 0.3552581             3
10 0.2600000 0.3281130 0.4118871             3
```

Comment: Good to know about this function, +1.